# Rails I18n transliteration rules configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initialization, translation, transliteration, rails-i18n

So, I wanted to pre-load the transliteration rules for many locales I have. I've included the following code in one of my initializers files (app/config/initializers/locales.rb):

```
I18n.backend.store_translations(:en, :i18n => {
:transliterate => {
    :rule => {
        "а" => "a",
        "б" => "b"
    }
}
})
```

But, if i try to make a transliteration: `I18n.transliterate("Some Russian text")`, I receive bunch of "?" signs, meaning that the transliterator doesn't have rules, so he doesn't know how to make a transliteration.

**BUT!**

If I have them (rules) defined in locales file (en.yml) like this:

```
en:
  i18n:
    transliterate:
      rule:
        а: "а"
        б: "b"
```

Then **it works** - Although I have a question, regarding HOW it works. 
If I specify `I18n.transliterate("абвгд")` - works good, but If I do `"абвгд".parameterize`, for some pescy reason, the letter "a" is being **ommited** (Like if there was no "a" letter in the first place).

WHY ?

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have got a cyrillic 'а' (char code 1072) mapped to a cyrillic 'а' in your en.yml. Do you just need to map cyrillic 'а' to roman 'a'?

```
en:
  i18n:
    transliterate:
      rule:
        а: "a"
        б: "b"
```

(both seem to look the same on this site I think).

Comment: I needed to map cyrillic "a" to latin (?) "a".

Comment: OK, so basically having that one fixed (I think), why can't I use initializers to load the transliteration rules ?